# Odd Table implementation - can Atata support this oddness?

Tags: atata

I have a table thus:

```html
<tbody>
  <tr class="bg-light">
    <th scope="col" width="300">Custom Field Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Data</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="test-custom-field-row">
    <td>Character 1900</td>
    <td>Thing 1</td>
  </tr>
```

Notice the header inside the first row object.  So, I can't do anything cool like:

CustomDisplayFields.Rows[x => x.Name == "Character1900"].Data.Should...

because we choke on the first row, because there are no <td> objects in it.  Is there any Yevgeniy Attribute magic that tells the table definition to ignore the first row?  Here's my table implementation:

```
    public Table<Field, _> CustomDisplayFields { get; private set; }

    public class Field : TableRow<_>
    {
        [FindByColumnIndex(0)]
        public Text<_> Name { get; private set; }

        [FindByColumnIndex(1)]
        public Text<_> Data { get; private set; }
    }
```

Thanks ever-so-much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify row control definition with XPath that skips the first row. Try to add one of the below attributes to your `Field` table row class.

```
[ControlDefinition("tr[position() > 1]", ComponentTypeName = "row")]
```

Or

```
[ControlDefinition("tr[td]", ComponentTypeName = "row")]
```

The first one just skips the first row. The second one selects only rows that have `td` as a child.

Comment: Yevgeniy Attribute magic does it again.  Thanks a ton.